# Initializing a final field in a constructor using Class.this.field = value gives an error whereas using this.field = value doesn't

Tags: java, constructor, field, final

```
class A {
    final int a;
    A () {
        this.a = 1; // No error
    }
}
```

whereas the below code

```
class A {
    final int a;
    A () {
        A.this.a = 1; // Error: java: cannot assign a value to final variable a
    }
}
```

Using `this.a` to assign a value to a final field works fine. But using `A.this.a` to assign a value to the final field gives an error "java: cannot assign a value to final variable a". Not sure why?

I understand that there are no reason in this case to explicitly use `A.this.a` instead of `this.a`. Just wanted to understand the reason.

Comment: `A.this`, refers to an existing instance of `A`. of which you cannot change final fields. Assigning a value to `this.a` (or just `a`) only works inside the constructor.

Comment: Can you please help me to understand why and how `A.this` refer to an existing instance of A?

Comment: this is nothing but the current object calling the method or constructor and what you are trying to refer(this) current object though class name, which is invalid in java.

Comment: @ShekharKhairnar if the field is not declared final, there are no errors.

Comment: @f1sh Can you please help me to understand why and how `A.this` refer to an existing instance of A?

Comment: @ShekharKhairnar it is not invalid. `A.this` is valid syntax to refer to `this`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this [bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8193904?focusedId=14542315&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-14542315), JVM architect John Rose mentioned that the definite assignment (DA) of blank final fields (e.g. `a` in your code) are only tracked by the simple name `a`, and `this.a`. Other more complex expressions like `A.this.a` are not considered when determining whether the field is definitely assigned.

> In the present case, the rather arbitrary choice was made (by Bill Joy and me, IIRC, back in Java 1.1 times) to perform static checking of blank final non-static field initialization by tracking uses of either the bare field name "x" or the simply qualified field name "this.x" but by no other, more complex expression. In other words, this "bug" is an intentional feature in the design of the JLS.

He explains the reasoning further:

> we wanted to allow only the bare field name "x" to participate in the static analysis of DU/DA; this would be the simplest formulation of the DU/DA rules. We added exactly "this.x" as an alternative in order to respect the reasonable practice of giving constructor parameters and fields the same names (a practice confirmed by Java records).
>
> But keeping this names tracked by DU/DA as simple as possible is important, because they are already complex enough that the compiler has to train the user (with error messages like the one this bug reports) how to stay within the bounds of DU/DA correctness. Arbitrarily adding a more complex grammar of names that DU/DA works on adds to the complexity of an already hard-to-predict analysis. It makes code harder to read and mentally validate, in particular.

In short, this is an arbitrary choice. They kept the DA rules simple.